# To handle multiple content extension in Notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, unnotificationserviceextension, notification-content-extension

I had to show different UI for multiple categories using Notification content and service extension, for example, one UI can have an image with only title and subtitle, another can have some info with target buttons. How to handle as a content extension have single storyboard with default ViewController class . Any answer would be appreciated.